# How can I use SQL to combine columns into one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question based on my project, in order to describe the question clearly, I extract 3 simplified tables below to demonstrate.

The First Table P_COURSE and the data inside.

```
COURSE_ID, PRIMARY_INSTRUCTOR_ID
---------------------------------
1            1
2            4
```

The Second Table P_COURSE_OTHER_INSTRUCTOR and the data inside.

```
COURSE_ID, INSTRUCTOR_ID
-------------------------
1            2
1            3
2            5
```

The Third Table P_INSTRUCTOR and the data inside.

```
INSTRUCTOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
-----------------------------------
1           Furtado      Rico
2           Steptoe      Anne
3           Beaton       Alan
4           Fuston       Arch
5           Hoyano       Aida
```

The output I desired is:

```
COURSE_ID, INSTRUCTORS
-----------------------------------
1        Furtado Rico, Steptoe Anne, Beaton Alan
2        Fuston Arch, Hoyano Aida
```

Is there any way graceful to get the result? I know I can use build-in function LISTAGG() on other instructors, but how can I deal with the primary instructor?

Comment: Which version of Oracle?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
  COURSE_ID,
  listagg(FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME, ',') 
    within group (order by COURSE_ID) as list 
from 
(
  SELECT COURSE_ID, PRIMARY_INSTRUCTOR_ID
  FROM P_COURSE

  UNION ALL

  SELECT COURSE_ID, INSTRUCTOR_ID
  FROM P_COURSE_OTHER_INSTRUCTOR
)x 
  INNER JOIN P_INSTRUCTOR y 
  on x.PRIMARY_INSTRUCTOR_ID=y.INSTRUCTOR_ID
group by COURSE_ID
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe50d/5)